# Solaris fmadm equivalent for FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, solaris, illumos

I've been looking for the equivalent of `fmadm`, the fault management configuration tool of Solaris / illumos on FreeBSD. But I'm unable to find an equivalent or even a subset of tools that mimics the features of `fmadm`.

What kind of software I should be looking for on FreeBSD to at least mimic some features of `fmadm`?

Comment: What specific functionality are you looking for? There may not be a direct equivalent.

Comment: Specifically the centralized faulty facility for system events. The fixes and repair utilities can be done with other system tools when we know what happened.